# Get projected value from std::ranges algorithms

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I am using algorithms from `std::ranges` (`max` and `max_element`) with a projection.
Is it possible for the result to also be the projected value? Currently I have to call the projection function again on the returned value.

**Example**:
Here I want the size of the longest string, but the algorithms return only the string or an iterator to it.

```
int main()
{
    const std::vector<std::string> vec = {
        "foo",
        "hello",
        "this is a long string",
        "bar"
    };

    //r1 is a string. r2 is an iterator
    const auto r1 = std::ranges::max(vec, {}, &std::string::size);
    const auto r2 = std::ranges::max_element(vec, {}, &std::string::size);
    
    //I have to call size() again
    std::cout << r1 << '\n' << *r2 << '\n';
    std::cout << r1.size() << '\n' << r2->size() << std::endl;
}
```

[Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/7chYavPrq)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using an algorithm (`max`/`max_element`) on the original range, which can't do anything but give you an element/iterator into the range.

If you want just the projected values, do the projection (via a `views::transform`) to get the lengths first, and then find the maximum of that

```
auto const lens = std::views::transform(vec, &std::string::size);

const auto r1 = std::ranges::max(lens);
const auto r2 = std::ranges::max_element(lens);

std::cout << r1 << '\n' << *r2 << '\n';  // prints 21 21
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1G438M8xY).

---

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70566451), taking the address of `std::string::size` is not permitted, so you should use a lambda instead. In general though, taking a projection based on a member function works just fine, so long as it's not a std function.

Answer (score 5):

> Here I want the size of the longest string, but the algorithms return
> only the string or an iterator to it.

In fact, according to [[namespace.std#6]](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.std#6):

> Let `F` denote a standard library function ([global.functions]), a
> standard library static member function, or an instantiation of a
> standard library function template. Unless `F` is designated an
> *addressable* function, **the behavior of a C++ program is unspecified
> (possibly ill-formed) if it explicitly or implicitly attempts to form
> a pointer to `F`.**

This is unspecified behavior since you are forbidden to extract the address of the `string::size`.

You can use `views::transform` to convert the original range to a range whose elements are the size value and then take the maximum value.

```
auto size = std::ranges::max(
              vec | std::views::transform([](auto& s) { return s.size(); }));
std::cout << size << '\n';
```

Comment: Good point, I always forget about not taking the address of std functions.

Comment: Oh I did not know that, thanks. I use a lambda for my more complicated case so it should be fine